# $JAVA_HOME not matching with java -version on git bash (last update)

Tags: java, windows, variables, environment-variables, git-bash

I had to set up back my java installation. Since the installation, the `java -version` and the `$JAVA_HOME` don't match in GitBash. The path is false so I can't execute Java CLI from it, I have to use the Windows CMD.. How can I fix this problem?

Yesterday, I uninstall Java from `C/Program Files/Java` and install the update (after deletting all java's folders) in `C/Java`.

From the Windows CMD, the java version and it's path match :

```
C:\Users\Quentin.FRL-FKNJNQ2>java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

C:\Users\Quentin.FRL-FKNJNQ2>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
```

And when I do the equivalent command on GitBash, here is what I got :

```
Quentin@FRL-FKNJNQ2 MINGW64 ~
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

Quentin@FRL-FKNJNQ2 MINGW64 ~
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/
```

The Path on GitBash is the one of the old java version. The folder pointed by the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` doesn't exist anymore.

I have already tried to uninstall java and gitbash then to install them back, but it didn't fix the problem..

Does someone know how to fix or any idea of where to search?

Thanks in advance ;)

PS : The issue has bin solved.

The path had to be rewritten in `bashrc`

---

Here is what I get running GitBash -x :

- $JAVA_HOME

```
Quentin@FRL-FKNJNQ2 MINGW64 /
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
 + echo /C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/
/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/
++ __git_ps1
++ local exit=0
++ local pcmode=no
++ local detached=no
++ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
++ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
++ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
++ case "$#" in
++ printf_format=' (%s)'
++ local ps1_expanded=yes
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '4.4.23(1)-release' ']'
++ shopt -q promptvars
++ local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
+++ git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD
++ repo_info=
++ rev_parse_exit_code=128
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ return 0
```

- java -version

```
Quentin@FRL-FKNJNQ2 MINGW64 /
$ java -version
+ java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
++ __git_ps1
++ local exit=0
++ local pcmode=no
++ local detached=no
++ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
++ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
++ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
++ case "$#" in
++ printf_format=' (%s)'
++ local ps1_expanded=yes
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '4.4.23(1)-release' ']'
++ shopt -q promptvars
++ local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
+++ git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD
++ repo_info=
++ rev_parse_exit_code=128
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ return 0
```

Comment: When you execute `java` the `PATH`is used not `JAVA_HOME`. `JAVA_HOME` is only used by java apps who need to find the compiler of the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Run GitBash with [`-x` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409366/what-is-bash-x) to enable debug. This will output trace for every command executed by bash. You should be able to tell at which point `JAVA_HOME` env variable is set to `jdk1.8.0_181`.